# Xstream does not deserialize custom object list

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I have some trouble deserializing an implicit collection with xStream

I have two classes:

One:

```
@XStreamAlias("instances")
public class ServerInstances {

  public ServerInstances(){
      instances = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "instance")
  private List<ServerInstance> instances;

  ...add, get, size, etc.
}
```

Two:

```
@XStreamAlias("instance")
public class ServerInstance {

  @XStreamAlias("version")
  private String version;

  @XStreamAlias("environment")
  private String environment;

  @XStreamAlias("user")    
  private String user;

  @XStreamAlias("timestamp")
  private DateTime timeStamp;

  getter, setter, etc.

}
```

When I serialize the ServerInstances class

```
    xStream = new XStream2();
    xStream.registerConverter(new DateTimeConverter());
    xStream.processAnnotations(new Class[] {ServerInstances.class, ServerInstance.class});
    xStream.toXMLUTF8(object, outputStream);
```

I get nice xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<instances plugin="jenkins-deployment-dashboard@0.0.1">
  <instance>
    <version>1</version>
    <environment>i1</environment>
    <user>u1</user>
    <timestamp>2014-10-10T11:42:30.957+02:00</timestamp>
  </instance>
  <instance>
    <version>2</version>
    <environment>i2</environment>
    <user>u2</user>
    <timestamp>2014-10-10T11:42:30.991+02:00</timestamp>
  </instance>
</instances>
```

But when I try to deserialize it

```
xStream = new XStream2();
xStream.registerConverter(new DateTimeConverter());
xStream.processAnnotations(new Class[] {ServerInstances.class, ServerInstance.class});
ServerInstances instances = (ServerInstances)xStream.fromXml(inputStream);
```

I get an instance of ServerInstances where the List is null.
I also tried to announce the aliases by using xStream.alias(...) and xStream.addImplicitCollection(...) which produces the same result. I have no idea what to do anymore.

Comment: What is `XStream2` and does the deserialization work if you use a normal `XStream` instead?

Comment: Oh sorry. I wanted to remove all instance of XStream2 to avoid this confusion. This is for a jenkins plugin and XStream2 is a jenkins utility class that extends Xstream. But you're right. I will try it with common XStream.

Comment: Update: Basic XStream doesn't work either. :(

Comment: I take that back. I made the mistake of only changing the field type but not the instantiation of the object so I was still using XStream2. m-|